# Where may I find an exhaustive list of the CSS classnames for Firefox DevTools?

Tags: firefox, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

I'd like to change a few properties of the Firefox **Developer Tools** such as the font sizes of various windows for my own readability.

I know the names of some of the classes but not all of the ones I want. Where may I find an exhaustive list of such classes?

In fact, where may I find the default stylesheet Firefox uses for **Developer Tools**?

Comment: Do you know you can simply zoom in by pressing Ctrl + +?

Comment: @SebastianZartner Thank you. I discovered soon after posting the question and have since even used it more than one video I made. BTW, since you and I have bumped into each other here earlier, and I get the feeling you might be able to tell Mozilla Foundation to recommend a change in the way SessionStorage is implemented not just in Firefox but in all browsers. Is this a bug? https://youtu.be/IZlo1mLymbU

Comment: As you assumed in your video, `sessionStorage` is indeed a `Window` object and tied to a "top-level browsing context", i.e. the current tab in your browser. See the related [MDN page mentioning this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). If you want to store data independently of the tab you're in, you should use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). It's far more complicated to use but also has huge benefits over the session storage.

Comment: @SebastianZartner Ah, I never saw that text in bold. Thanks much. :-) BTW, can you tell the Mozilla folks to change the implementation of the HTML5 Storage API so that `localStorage.getItem("foo")` does not return the string `"undefined"` instead of the value `undefined` after having called `localStorage.setItem("foo", undefined)`? I made another video about this here: https://youtu.be/tF7kqpsy884

Comment: As this discussion is out of scope of your question and the comment area of Stack Overflow is not a forum, I've replied in a comment on your video.